# How to debug "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'readline'" in Python?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    found = False
    coffee_file = ('c:/test/coffee.txt', 'r')
    search = input("Enter a description to search :- ")

    descr = coffee_file.readline()

    while (descr != ''):
        qty = (coffee_file.readline())
        descr = descr.rstrip('\n')
        qty = qty.rstrip('\n')

        if ('search' == descr):
            print("Description :- ", descr)
            print("Quantity :- ", qty)
            print

            found = True

        descr = coffee_file.readline()

    coffee_file.close()


main()
```

Throws me `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'readline'`.

Comment: This is  how my file looks like and its trying to read data from below information :-
Description :- Indian Coffee
Quantity :- 10
Description :- Sri Coffee
Quantity :- 11
Description :- China Coffee
Quantity :- 12

Comment: My eror log :-

Enter a description to search :- Indian Coffee
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jimmyj/Desktop/read a file with for loop.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/jimmyj/Desktop/read a file with for loop.py", line 7, in main
    descr=coffee_file.readline()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'readline'
>>>

Comment: You should replase this `coffee_file=('c:/test/coffee.txt','r')` with `coffee_file=open('c:/test/coffee.txt','r')`. Also, you should add `break` statement to your loop or use `for line in coffee_file` instead.

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov :- Thank you ... I need your 2 help here .. Sorry to bother but im new to python . Your assistance will really help me .
1. I changed to coffee_file=open('c:/test/coffee.txt','r') but still it doesnt provide me any error and desired o/p

2. Please help me to complete using for ...(I tried , but i miss logic here )

Comment: Please add your error log to the question, rather than just leaving it in the comments.

Comment: Now , after modifying the code .. I am not getting any error. But , I am not getting the desired o/p

Enter a description to search :- Indian Coffee
Description :-  Indian Coffee
Quantity :- not found
>>> 
O/p Should be like 
Description :-  Indian Coffee
Quantity :- 10

Comment: def main():
    found = False
    search = input("Enter a description to search :- ").rstrip()

    with open('c:/test/coffee.txt') as coffee_file:
        for line in coffee_file:
            qty = line.rstrip()
            if search == qty:
                print("Description :- ", search)
                print("Quantity :- ", qty)
                found = True

    if not found:
        print("Description :- ", search)
        print("Quantity :- not found")

main()

Answer (score 0):

1. Your error was in `coffee_file=('c:/test/coffee.txt','r')` line. You should write `coffee_file=open('c:/test/coffee.txt','r')`. I replaced that by contex manager, using `with` statement.
2. Your `while` loop was infinite, so I used `for` loop.
3. You were comparing string "search" with variable "descr", which was the first line of the file.

Assuming that you want to find promoted string in file - this code should work:

```
def main():
    found = False
    search = input("Enter a description to search :- ").rstrip()

    with open('c:/test/coffee.txt') as coffee_file:
        for line in coffee_file:
            qty = line.rstrip()
            if search == qty:
                print("Description :- ", search)
                print("Quantity :- ", qty)
                found = True

    if not found:
        print("Description :- ", search)
        print("Quantity :- not found")

main()
```

P.S. Please, provide your input data (In this case - `c:/test/coffee.txt`) sample and expected output next time.

Comment: My Sample data will be :-+
++++++++++++++++++++
Description :- Indian Coffee
Quantity :- 10
Description :- Sri Coffee
Quantity :- 11
Description :- China Coffee
Quantity :- 12
Description :- America
Quantity :- 15

Expected o/p:
Description :-
Quantity :-

Comment: @Jijith i can, but could you edit your post instead of posting data in comment ? Without proper fotmatting its hard to guess how your script should work